Usage of んだからって in this sentence
その人実は自殺願望があったんだ」
「年上の人で社会人で…だからそんな大人が悩んでるんだからってあんまり強く言えなかった」
「気にしてる、好きだって伝えてはいたよ。でも死んでほしくない、一緒に居て欲しいって強く言えなくて…」
The character is talking about a past lover of them and they describe them this way.
What I'm stumbled is 大人が悩んでるんだからって.
The first part is 年上の人で社会人で is "They were older and a working citizen..." and "ってあんまり強く言えなかった」" is i couldn't say.
But I'm stumbled on how だからそんな大人が悩んでるんだからって is divided. Obviously だから is "that's why"  and I'd assume って here is quote but what to make of そんな大人が悩んでるんだから?
From context I can make it "I'm I couldn't say I'm worried about you" but が悩んでる is intransitive so...?

I don't think って is providing a quote connected to the 言えなかった at the end of the sentence, but rather is giving further context as to why "[they] couldn't speak harshly."

@Zylviij I believe this sentence is using って as in ということは, the grammar that generally equates to "in other words," right?

This って is abbreviated って思って.

Meaning of と in 友蔵が出おくれまいと言いそえた
Embedded question followed by と
What does かけまいと mean here?


だから「そんな大人が悩んでるんだから」って（思って）、あんまり強く言えなかった。
So, thinking "such an adult is troubled, so...", I couldn't say [my words] strongly.
→ I knew it was a grown-up who was troubled, and that's why I couldn't speak up.

Here, the speaker is thinking that an adult's troubles are not something she can interfere with.
EDIT: だからって is more commonly an abbreviation of だからといって. For example, 大人だからって何でもしていいわけじゃない means "Just because you're an adult doesn't mean you can do anything". I would say the use of だからって in your sentence is indeed a bit tricky.
